# cannot download software from ubuntu software centres

Tags: updates

my system shows broken packages with the following information
pls help
libqt4-qt3support, scripttools and sql-Mysql 
installed vwesion is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.5 while latest version is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.8
when i am trying to fix it it shows error msg that unable to configure due to change in versions it is also not allowing to download any further software from ubuntu software centre

Comment: can you please add the output from terminal with those errors? run `sudo apt-get -f install`